# android, Manifest shows error for android:targetSdkVersion

Tags: android

I have defined following line in My manifest file but an error occurs.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

and the error message is:

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'targetSdkVersion'
>   in package 'android'

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: I think you have to update your sdk...

Comment: do you have install 2.2 version ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

android:targetSdkVersion was added in api level 4 which is android 1.6. Make sure you are compiling your project with 1.6 and above  and you have not set 1.5 as build target.

Comment: I have a full sample code and when I copy this part of that code into my manifest, it shows error. I'm sure that the original code maker did not have problem with this. But I can't understand why he didn't have problem with this line?!!!

Comment: Are you sure your project build target is not set to 1.5. Right click on project--> properties -->android-- > project build target. As android:targetSdkVersion is not available in 1.5 it will generate error if build target is set to 1.5.

Comment: @anujprashar, but using Eclipse why it worked fine? This error only came when I switch to Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above, make sure you delete the project's bin directory too so it's rebuilt with the updated android build target.